# How do I invoke another function on another react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new in es6, this code works in React.createClass. I have a total 2 function that I want to pass on another component, my problem is I am confused with its' context, my code is like this:

```
class AppOne extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 this.state = {
      timers: [
        {
            title: 'Practice squat',
            project: 'Gym Chores',
            id: v4(),
            elapsed: 5456099,
            runningSince: Date.now()
        },
        {
            title: 'Bake squash',
            project: 'Kitchen Chores',
            id: v4(),
            elapsed: 1273998,
            runningSince: null
        },
      ],
    };

  this.func = this.func.bind(this);
  this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this); //<--"Uncaught TypeError: this.stopTimer is 
// not a function"
 } 

 func(timerId) {
        this.stopTimer(timerId);
 }

 stopTimer(timerId) {
    const now = Date.now();

    this.setState({
        timers: this.state.timers.map((timer) => {
            if(timer.id === timerId) {
                const lastElapsed = now - timer.runningSince;
                return Object.assign({}, timer, {
                    elapsed: timer.elapsed + lastElapsed,
                    runningSince: null
                });
            } else {
                return timer;
            }
        }),
    });
}

 render() {
  return (
   <AppTwo handleFuncFromAppOne = {this.func} timers={this.state.timers} />
  );
 }
}

class AppTwo extends React.Component {
 handleFuncFromAppTwo() {
  this.props.handleFuncFromAppOne(this.props.timers.id)
 }
 render() {
  return(
   <AppThree handleFuncFromAppThree={this.handleFuncFromAppTwo} />
  );
 }
}

class AppThree extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div
    className='ui bottom attached red basic button'
    onClick={this.props.handleFuncFromAppThree} // I want to invoke here
   >
    Stop
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

You see I already bind stopTimer its' this on App One and it use this.setState to change the state, my problem is I cannot Invoke it on App three. My error is "Uncaught TypeError: this.stopTimer is not a function". I don't seem to have this problem with React.createClass. Help?

Comment: why are you calling stopTimer from 'func'? Also when is it creating this error? in the constructor or when calling func? Also if you already wrapped func, it will have this as context so you dont need to wrap stopTimer

Comment: @Kinnza, in my original code it's a separate component which is a set of buttons in a component, the id is passed as props on AppTwo, and invoked on AppThree..

Comment: @iamnewbie and kinnza  I think i answered your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your problem is you are not passing reference of the class where you defined `handleFuncFromAppThree()` you can do like this:

//class Apptwo

```
 render() {
  return(
   <AppThree parentObje={this} /> //pass reference not function
  );
 }

//class AppThree

<div
    className='ui bottom attached red basic button'
    onClick={this.props.parentObj.handleFuncFromAppThree()} // invoke the //function like this
   >
```

you can so similarly for class Appone.

Cheers:)

Comment: it does work! Thank you, but is there another way to do it? Like, you don't have to pass the parentObj props from child to child?

Comment: Yeah well this is really not the way to do this you shouldnt pass the parent object to the child object.... If you pass the method from the parent then bind it there and not inside your component.